# Android notification returns to the wrong activity

Tags: java, android

**Hi all,**
I am implementing a notification in a service which when clicking on the notification once it appears - It opens an activity.
I have this code in my service class inside a runnable that runs nonstop every few seconds:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email)
            .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
            .setContentText(notificationMessage);

    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigText = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();

    builder.setStyle(bigText);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, openemailactivity.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

In my notification activity named "openemailactivity" I have a button which has a code in it to return the user to the home activity called "MainActivity":

```
btnReturnToMainScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Everything works fine until I restart my Android phone, the service loads on boot (as intended) and then generates a notification and then I click on it.
Then, when I click on it, the "openemailactivity" activity opens well also as intended, and then I click the button that opens the "MainActivity" (The above code) and it does that O.k.

**And now the problem starts !**

After this other activity was opened ("MainActivity"), and then the notification pops up again by the service (Notification timer\checking runs in a timed Handler\Runnable that runs nonstop) - and then I click on the notification itself that was created -
 ***the activity that it should call ("openemailactivity") is not called anymore !*** instead - the last called activity pops up ("MainActivity"), which is wrong !

The problem starts only when I restart my phone, the service loads on boot, notification is generated, I click on it, It opens the right activity, and then I call the code from the button (OnClickListener).

I don't have a clue on how to solve this problem.

What do you think can be the problem ?
What am I doing wrong and how can I solve it ?

Thanks for any reply.

Comment: try adding Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED to pendingIntent and update here

Comment: Hello and thanks for your quick answer. I tried to add the flag to the pendingIntent. It cannot be done because it does not accept it according to my code above, So I added the flag to the resultIntent instead. After testing it - It did nothing. The problem still exists.

Comment: I think that I found an answer. You surely gave me a nice clue - Too add some kind of flag to the intent. Please see my following answer further on this page. Thanks again for the hint !

Answer (score 0):

Strange but it looks like I found an answer (Hopefully - It needs to get more comprehensive testing since Surprises always exist in this environment).

I tried to set:

```
resultIntent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

in the notification code that exists in the service, right after declaring this variable (resultIntent).

As for now it looks like it works !
By looking at the Android documentation for this flag, it looks like it may explain the problem that I had:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html
(Search for the explanation of: "FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP").